# Destructure Event parameters and only pass type check if id is of a certain value

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an event handler hooked up to a button. The button has an id of `'whatever'`. In the parameters of the event handler, I want to destructure the event like this `({ target: { id })`, but I only want the TypeScript type checker to be successful if the id is equal to `'whatever'`. How can I achieve this?

```
const handleClick = ({ target: { id }) => { // Only pass type check if id = 'whatever'
  console.log('hello world')
}

return (
  <div>
    <button
      id="whatever"
      onClick={handleClick}
    >
    <button
      id="somethingElse"
      onClick={handleClick} {/* I don't want this to pass the type check */}
    >
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of destructuring the EventTarget, try to declare the parameter as a `React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>` and access its `id` via the `currentTarget` property:

```
const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
  // Only pass type check if id = 'whatever'
  if (e.currentTarget.id === 'whatever') return;
  console.log('hello world');
};
```